# Disable all past dates in android default CalendarView?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to disable all past date (including the days that fall in past but in the same month) in `CalendarView` (default). Here is the screenshot of the `CalendarView`.
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5x3w.jpg)

Every answer i searched was about disabling it in android `DatePickerDailog`.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @Ajay S That answer helped me to disable past months only and not the days.

Comment: Solved it by using following code: `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.getInstance().getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        long date = calendar.getTime().getTime();
        mCalendarView.setMinDate(date);`